# Kickstart | Joomla 1.6 restoring a site

Tags: joomla, akeeba

I am trying to restore a joomla site, and is my first time doingit so bear with me.
I was trying to restore a site with Akeeba kickstart, however it only accepts jpa however I have a tar.gz, even the owner does not have idea how long has zipped file been around. However, It was mention that the old joomla site was running version 1.6 or 1.7.

Then my question comes which might be the best ways to get back the post from that old tar.gz

Any suggestions more than welcome

I created a free website in https://ccp.cloudaccess.net install joomla 4, used kickstart but it only accepts jpa, or zip files (yes, i tried making the tar a zip, not the best idea but you know I am kind of desperate)